# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string Python3-MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, typeerror, pymysql

I have written a web app that takes input and stores it in a MySQL db. I have created a search field on the web app, so that one could input a string and it will search all columns for the data input and return it.

Originally my pymysql script for the search looked like this.

```
  try:
    with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
        sql = """SELECT * FROM main WHERE Concat(idDirectConnect_ID,
                                         CR_Number,
                                         VPC_Name,
                                         Creator_Name,
                                         Route_Domain,
                                         OSPF_ASN,
                                         OSPF_VLAN,
                                         OSPF_Subnet,
                                         BGP_VLAN,
                                         BGP_Subnet,
                                         BGP_AuthKey is null,
                                         AWS_Expected_Subnet,
                                         AWS_Acnt,
                                         Company_Name,
                                         Lpbck_Int,
                                         Lpbck_IPAddr,
                                         Tunnel_Num1,
                                         Tunnel_Num2,
                                         VPN_Tunnel1_Dest is null,
                                         VPN_Int1_CryptoKey is null,
                                         VPN_Tun1_IP is null,
                                         VPN_Tunnel2_Dest is null,
                                         VPN_Int2_CryptoKey is null,
                                         VPN_Tun2_IP is null,
                                         AWS_VPN_ConnectionID is null)
                                         LIKE %s;"""
        cursor.execute(sql, ('%{}%'.format(sql_var)))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
finally:
    connection.close()
```

This worked except when there was data in the columns marked is null. These columns are null when first created and my remain so for a while, however there is searchable data in the other columns.

As a result, I am trying to update my search query to:

```
    try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """SELECT * FROM main WHERE (idDirectConnect_ID LIKE %s
                                         OR CR_Number LIKE %s
                                         OR VPC_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Creator_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Route_Domain LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_ASN LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_VLAN LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_VLAN LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_Expected_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_Acnt LIKE %s
                                         OR Company_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Lpbck_Int LIKE %s
                                         OR Lpbck_IPAddr LIKE %s
                                         OR Tunnel_Num1 LIKE %s
                                         OR Tunnel_Num2 LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_AuthKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tunnel1_Dest LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Int1_CryptoKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tun1_IP LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tunnel2_Dest LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Int2_CryptoKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tun2_IP LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_VPN_ConnectionID LIKE %s);"""
        cursor.execute(sql, ", ".join(["'%{}%'".format(sql_var)]*25))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
finally:
    connection.close()
```

but I am getting:

```
query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I originally had only:

```
 cursor.execute(sql, ('%{}%'.format(sql_var)))
```

but I realized there weren't enough arguments for all of the %s's, so I altered the cursor.execute to:

```
 cursor.execute(sql, ", ".join(["'%{}%'".format(sql_var)]*25))
```

Now its returning:

```
"'%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%', '%206%'"
```

I've counted them and recounted them and I've counted and recounted the %s's and there should be enough.

I've read through as many similar SO posts as I could find and the MySQL docs. At this point I suspect I may need to change the cursor to an executemany, but its just a guess.

Comment: The thing you have under 'Now it's returning' is a *string*. If you look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html you will read that the second parameter of `execute` should be either a tuple or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction.

Here is my working code:

```
try:
    with connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
        sql = """SELECT * FROM main WHERE (idDirectConnect_ID LIKE %s
                                         OR CR_Number LIKE %s
                                         OR VPC_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Creator_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Route_Domain LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_ASN LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_VLAN LIKE %s
                                         OR OSPF_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_VLAN LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_Expected_Subnet LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_Acnt LIKE %s
                                         OR Company_Name LIKE %s
                                         OR Lpbck_Int LIKE %s
                                         OR Lpbck_IPAddr LIKE %s
                                         OR Tunnel_Num1 LIKE %s
                                         OR Tunnel_Num2 LIKE %s
                                         OR BGP_AuthKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tunnel1_Dest LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Int1_CryptoKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tun1_IP LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tunnel2_Dest LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Int2_CryptoKey LIKE %s
                                         OR VPN_Tun2_IP LIKE %s
                                         OR AWS_VPN_ConnectionID LIKE %s);"""
        cursor.execute(sql, list(['%{}%'.format(sql_var)]*25))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
finally:
    connection.close()
```

I also had to change the cursor back to a DictCursor as the rest of the python code required that format.